# AngularJS 2 OnSelect Returns Error

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to follow the Angular 2 tutorial, which is in TypeScript, but in JavaScript.  Unfortunately I've hit a snag and I can't find a solution searching online.  Right now I'm on the Master/Detail step.  I'm defining an onSelect element but when I define my onSelect function I get back the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined`

Here is my code:

app.component.js:

```
(function(app) {
app.AppComponent =
ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
            <h2>My Heros</h2>
            <ul class="heroes">
                <li *ngFor="let hero of Heroes" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
                    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div *ngIf="selectedHero">
                <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
                <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
                <div>
                    <label>name: </label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
                </div>
            </div>
  `
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {
            this.title = 'Tour of Heros'; 
            this.Heroes = Heroes; 
            this.onSelect(hero) {
                this.selectedHero = hero;
            };
  }
});
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

function Hero (id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
};

var Heroes = [
new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nice'),
new Hero(12, 'Narco'),
new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
new Hero(14, 'Celeritas'),
new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
new Hero(16, 'RubberMan'),
new Hero(17, 'Dynama'),
new Hero(18, 'Dr. IQ'),
new Hero(19, 'Magma'),
new Hero(20, 'Tornado')
];
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart JS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfill -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/main.js'></script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

If I remove the `this.onSelect(hero) {this.selectedHero = hero;};` it works fine, minus the ability to select an element.  I've tried defining selectedHero with a default value and still the same error occurs.  How do I define the onSelect function?

Comment: Do you have a `<my-app></my-app>` tag in the `<body>` tag of your `index.html` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
this.onSelect(hero) {
```

should be

```
this.onSelect = function (hero) {
```

Comment: I feel pretty dull for not thinking of that.

Comment: No need :D. So many things to consider if you are not yet comfortable with some new tech stuff.